# How to build a website based on spaced repetition learning?

Tags: algorithm

I want to build a website to help the users memorize notes with space-repetition. The website will already have all the questions/answers pairs and the user will have to visit the website everyday to review the pair. When a pair is due to be reviewed, the question is displayed on screen, and the user must attempt to answer. After answering, the user manually reveals the answer and then tells the website (subjectively) how difficult answering was. The program schedules pairs based on spaced repetition algorithms.

I already know the basics of Python and HTML but have no clue where to start. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Unfortunately your question is too broad and thus invites opinion-based answers which are discouraged on this site. Please visit SO Help Center section on 'Asking' and read **both** the first two FAQs >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on a project with python and HTML.

I recommend you to use Flask.

> What is Flask?

Flask is a web framework made for python.

> Are there alternatives

Yes, they are alternatives for flask! Maby Django can do the job.

Hope it helped!
By the way, you can also use MYSQL for the job!

Also : I am using flask for my webapps, altho python is not very good in the web

Thanks,
ananth